# Kuhn-Tucker constraint qualification, overdetermined?

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have a question about the constraint qualification for KKT. As I've seen the theorem stated if $G(x^*)=(g_1(x^*),\dots,g_n(x^*))$ are the binding constraints at a local max $x^*$ then the jacobian $DG(x^*)$ must have rank $n$. Obviously this is impossible if $n>\text{length}(x)$. In the examples I can think of for this case, this simply means that we cannot find a unique multiplier $\lambda$.

E.g. $\max x_2$ subject to $x_1^2 + x_2^2\leq 1$, $x_2\leq x_1 + 1$, and $x_2\leq 1-x_1$ with $x^*=(0,1)$.

So my question is, if per the theorem, KKT requires rank $n$ so that these overdetermined cases fail the constraint qualification, what might be going wrong? The theorem does not require a unique multiplier. Could we relax the constraint qualification to $DG(x^*)$ has full rank?

Regarding the last question. Here is my proof sketch for why I think this is possible.

Suppose the original problem is to maximize $f$ on the constraint set $\mathcal{D}=U\cap \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:G(x)\geq 0\}$ where $U$ is an open set. Assume all continuously differentiable.

Let $E=\{i:G^i(x^*)=0\}$ and suppose $|E|>n$ and rank($DG_E(x^*)$)$=n$. Then we can find $F\subsetneq E$ where rank($DG_F(x^*)$)$=n$.

Suppose $x^*$ is a local max of $f$ on the constraint set $\mathcal{D}'=U\cap \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:G_F(x)\geq 0\}$ where $U$ is an open set. Then $x^*$ is also a local max on the constraint sets defined by $G_E$ and $G$ where the former includes superfluous effective constraints and the latter includes ineffective constraints so that the constraint set only gets smaller while still allowing $x^*$.

If we can find a vector $(x^*, \mu^*)$ that solves the KKT conditions from the problem max $f$ on $\mathcal{D}'$, then $(x^*, \lambda^*)$ solves the KKT conditions for the original problem if $\lambda_i=\mu_i$ for $i\in F$ and $\lambda_i = 0$ otherwise. This proves the claim because for $E$ where $|E|>n$ then we must be able to find an $F$ and $(x^*, \mu^*)$ from which we construct the solution to the original problem.

I think I'm just missing optima on $\mathcal{D}$ are also optima on $\mathcal{D}'$.

Edit: Thought of a counterexample--so long as I am not abusing any definitions or the statement of KKT.

$\max x_1$ subject to $g_1(x)=x_1\geq0$, $x_2\geq0$ and $x_2\leq x_1^2$.

The solution is the only point in the feasible region, $(0,0)$, which is therefore trivially a local max. All constraints bind. The Jacobian has rank 2, but the FOCs would require the multiplier on $g_1$ to be negative.

Comment: Sounds like your prof forgot to select _only the active indices_, those $g_i$ where $g_i(x^*) = 0$.

Comment: I don't think that is it--that's exactly what I mean by binding.

Comment: Note that those are not necessary. If the CQ hold, we know that the KKT must hold in a minimum (or maximum). If they don't, we are screwed and don't know anything.

Comment: What do you mean by not necessary? As in if I am in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and I have $n>m$ binding constraints ($g_i(x^*)=0$), I can just throw away $n-m$?

Comment: Not really, it means if you have so many binding constraints, you _may_ be able to throw some away to get a set of constraints wich satisfy the CQ in $x^*$ and are equivalent there (so that the new $x^*$ is the same as the $x^*$ with all constraints). But if you're not, even if $x^*$ is a solution, it need not satisfy KKT if the CQ is not satisfied there.

Comment: In terms:
$$x^* \text{ solution} \wedge CQ(x^*) \Rightarrow KKT(x^*)$$
But
$$\neg CQ(x^*) \Rightarrow \text{ nothing known about } x^*$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. But are there any good counterexamples for this case? Just thinking in 2d, I can't help but think if I have a matrix with rank $\text{\length}(x)$, then I should have a basis and be able to find a $\lambda$ such that $Df(x^*)+ \sum_{i=1}Dg_i(x^*)=0$ and $\lambda\geq 0 $.

Comment: Indeed, in Sundaram's optimization theory, KKT is stated to require rank equal to the number of binding constraints. In Dixit's Optimization in Economic Theory, KKT is stated to only require full rank of the jacobian for binding constraints.

Comment: Nocedal/Wright's _Numerical Optimization_ agrees with Sundaram.

Comment: There are several constraint qualifications. Your condition for full rank is only one of them. The Guignard constraint qualification is the weakest possible.